# In python, how can I make an exact copy of a folder tree without the files?

Tags: python, directory, copy, directory-structure, directory-tree

I need to make a copy of a folder with all of its subfolders, but do it without any of the files coming with the directories.

In Python, I am using the `os.walk` function to go top-down in a directory to process lots of images in lots of sub-folders. I want to make an exact copy of this folder tree (that the os.walk function goes through) and have it in a different directory I specify. This is to allow me to save my output images in the equivalent copy of the folder they came from.

I tried:

```
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree
copy_tree("/a/b/c", "/x/y/z")
```

but have no clue how to edit it to what I want. How can I use a python command to copy an empty folder-tree to a directory I choose?

Should I use the `shutil.copytree` command or should I put something inside the for loop processing the images or something else?

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to create the output directories as you are writing the files, for example with `os.makedirs(..., exist_ok=True)`.

Comment: agreed with Matthiew. 
I thought about the same.
I personally would probably write the code in your os.walk() loop such, that you just create the target directory whenever needed instead of creating all upfront. 
However I posted one answer that works fine with python 3.8 and with prior versions if the target directory doesn't exist before calling the code

Comment: You mentioned having code in the os.walk() loop that the target directory is created when needed. What would that look like within the context of my loop? (Do I directly copy and paste `os.makedirs(..., exist_ok=True)` into my loop somewhere specific?)

Comment: Yes, this was definitely what I was looking for! Thank you guys! 

If you need help with the `os.makedirs(..., exist_ok=True)` then this link might help: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-makedirs-method/

Answer (score 0):

You could use `shutil.copytree` if you want to:

It has an `ignore` parameter, that will allow you to ignore items from being copied (in your case ignore all non directories)

```
import os
import shutil

def cptree(src, dst):

    def keep_only_dirs(path, files):
        to_ignore = [
            fname for fname in files
            if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, fname))
            ]
        return to_ignore

    # This works for python3 (<3.8), BUT the target directory MUST not exist
    shutil.copytree(src, dst, ignore=keep_only_dirs)

    # For python 3.8 you can use following code (Here the target directory can
    # already exist and only new directories will be added
    # shutil.copytree(src, dst, ignore=keep_only_dirs, dirs_exist_ok=True)
```

Alternatively if you don't have python3.8 and you want to be able to make the code working with an existing target directory, you could handcraft some code using `os.walk()`

If this is what you need tell me and I'll write an example.

Comment: I think your first comment is right: I should probably try to have it inside the code rather than separately making the folder tree.